# Update IOS app, does it need to be signed with the same xcode account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have hired an apple developer where he coded my app. To publish the app, I provided him with provisioning profile and certificate. He also has the ITunes connect credential.

However when he pushed up the build, he signed it with his xcode ID.

Basically my question is, if  I want to push an update in the future , does it have to use his xcode ID?  OR can I submit an update from any other xcode as long as I have the profile, certificate and ITunes connect credential

Thank you

PS: Coming from Android background so it is very confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit from any Mac and Xcode what you should be having is the Provisional Profile and ITunes connect credential. You can even create new certificate or add a team member to your developer account who can download the certificate, provisional profile and upload to your itunes account.

Comment: Oh Ok. That's great. So signing V1 with specific xcode credential does not mean that V2 has to be signed with the same xcode credential.

Comment: Yup... your project space is not dependent on xcode, you can download a new xcode version and build your project using that xcode. And while uploading to appstore you can download the profile and generate the certificate using the mac you are using.

Comment: But When sign using xcode it asks you for ID and PASS. Does the ID and pass have to be the same all the time? My developer used his ID and pass for xcode  (which is diff from iTunes credential)

Comment: Which ID and password?  In xcode you can add accounts in preferences, which is your itunes/developer account and xcode will only need id/pass while uploading app to appstore.

Comment: Hmm.. I just noticed the dev put his ID/pass during one of the phases. maybe I am mistaking. Ok thanks for the info +1